# Login credentials of Ubuntu Cloud server image

Tags: ubuntu, cloud, virtual-machine, openstack

I am trying to build a cloud infrastructure using VM's

In the Openstack manuals, it is mentioned that the images in [this link](http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/trusty/current/) contain, Openstack pre-installed.

I downloaded the `trusty-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img` file and I loaded it using KVM. I instantiated a Virtual Machine using this image but I am not able to login (using the console) or ssh into it.

I do not know the default username and password of that OS.

Also (a different question), I would like to build a Cloud using the 2 Virtual Machines, is it possible to use the same image?

Answer (score 31):

**18.04 setup step-by-step with `cloud-localds`**

In short you need on the host:

```
sudo apt-get install cloud-image-utils

cat >user-data <<EOF
#cloud-config
password: asdfqwer
chpasswd: { expire: False }
ssh_pwauth: True
EOF

cloud-localds user-data.img user-data

# user-data.img MUST come after the rootfs. 
qemu-system-x86_64 \
-drive file=ubuntu-18.04-server-cloudimg-amd64.img,format=qcow2 \
-drive file=user-data.img,format=raw \
-m 1G
...
```

and now you can login with:

- username: `ubuntu`
- password: `asdfqwer`

Here I describe a full minimal detailed working QEMU example: https://askubuntu.com/questions/281763/is-there-any-prebuilt-qemu-ubuntu-image32bit-online/1081171#1081171

Tested on an Ubuntu 18.04 host.

Comment: Still unable to login inside ubuntu 20.04.3 . Says Login incorrect. Any idea why so?

Comment: @watney I did a quick try on Ubuntu 21.04 and it didn't immediately work. Let me know if you find something else. Those Ubuntu cloud images are too flaky.

Comment: Same steps verified to work for ubuntu 20.04

Comment: On 20.04 ssh login works, console login doesn't. Still can't figure this out.

Comment: Works on 22.04 (jammy-server-cloudimg-amd64.img). I prefer `-hda` and `-hda` option: `qemu-system-x86_64 -hda ubuntu-18.04-server-cloudimg-amd64.img -hdb user-data.img -m 1G -enable-kvm`.
I noticed that the password is saved to the Ubuntu disk; so we can't change "password" in `user-data` after once booted.

Comment: cloud-image-utils doesn't exist in my distribution, a download of user-data.img would've been appreciated.

Answer (score 22):

How about this:

```
$ virt-customize -a bionic-server-cloudimg-amd64.img --root-password password:coolpass
```

- https://serverascode.com/2018/06/26/using-cloud-images.html
- https://www.kraxel.org/blog/2018/11/fedora-29-images/

Answer (score 8):

The default username for ubuntu image is `ubuntu`.
There is not a default password, and you can not ssh to the machine using username / password or connect through the VNC console. You have to use public / private key authentication method with ssh. Also sudo elevation for `ubuntu` account is passwordless.

After accessing for the first time your virtual machine, you can change those settings and enable username / password authentication for ssh.

Regarding your second question,
Yes, you can use the same image for multiple virtual machine.

Comment: how to use public/private key auth method? If I use ssh-copy-id -p 2222 ubuntu@localhost where 2222 is the redirected ssh port I get: Permission denied (public key).

Comment: @hlitz You have to upload your public while you are creating the VM. If you are using the UI, the is a step where the system prompts you for the public key. If you are using the console and the API to create the VM, there is a command (which I cannot recall right now) that you can use and pass your key.

Comment: I've tried xenial-server-cloudimg-arm64-uefi1.img from http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/xenial/20161029/ : login "ubuntu" doesn't work, it then requests the password, I tried empty - and it says "Login incorrect".

Comment: @SergeRogatch Quoting a part of my answer `There is not a default password, and you can not ssh to the machine using username / password or connect through the VNC console. You have to use public / private key authentication method with ssh. `

Comment: @Athafoud, I don't think I'm using SSH. I just booted the VM in QEmu and used the terminal where it started.

Comment: @SergeRogatch that's exactly the case, you can not use the terminal. Your only choice is to configure and use ssh.

Comment: @Athafoud , shall I post a separate question on how to do this?

Comment: @SergeRogatch Yes, I think that it will be better that way.

Comment: @SergeRogatch, did you post that question? Can you link to it?

Comment: @meshy, no, I can't find such question among my posted questions, and now I don't remember how I solved the issue, sorry.

Answer (score 8):

Mounting the image and then using chpasswd inside the chroot was the easiest solution for me:

```
modprobe nbd max_part=8 && qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd0 image.raw && mkdir a && mount /dev/nbd0p1 a
chroot a sh -c "echo 'root:password' | chpasswd"
umount ./a && rmdir a && qemu-nbd -d /dev/nbd0
```

Comment: This is the most neat way.

Answer (score 1):

The following code could be used to make the Ubuntu `cloudimg` usable on a Debian 7.2 (wheezy) machine:

```
apt-get install pwgen
apt-get install genisoimage
git clone -b master https://git.launchpad.net/cloud-utils

printf "#cloud-config\n" > user-data
printf "password: `pwgen 8 1`\nchpasswd: { expire: False }\nssh_pwauth: True\n" >> user-data
./cloud-utils/bin/cloud-localds user-data.img user-data
```

Subsequently, you'd start the image like this, from within a [`tmux`](http://mdoc.su/o/tmux.1) window to make sure it'll keep running even if you logout:

`kvm -m 2048 -smp 2 -hda ubuntu-18.10-server-cloudimg-amd64.img -hdb user-data.img -net nic -net user,hostfwd=tcp::1810-:22 -nographic`

You can then login into the machine as user `ubuntu` and the password as generated within the `user-data` file.  The login can be either through the serial console printed by `kvm` (which would normally be pretty slow, even if you have an ssh connection on top of it), or through `ssh` with `ssh ubuntu@localhost -p1810`.  The user `ubuntu` gets passwordless `sudo` access as root by default.

---

P.S. I've also tried playing with adding the `ssh-authorized-keys`, but `cloud-config` format seems very fragile, and at top level it's just ignored, whereas at a `users:` level as below, the whole `ubuntu` user seems to break (at least the password part of it).  Here's the code to get the keys into a format that's potentially legible for cloud-config:

```
printf "users:\n  - name: ubuntu\n    ssh-authorized-keys:\n" >> user-data
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ~/.ssh/authorized_keys | sed 's/^/      - /g' >> user-data
```

(Note that the `password`, apparently, may not be a valid field for the `users` specification, as it has a `passwd` hash instead, so, the whole thing breaks the prior code, because now the user ubuntu gets created without a password.)

Answer (score 1):

virt-customize just fail in my case, here I'm using virt-sysprep set the password ok.

```
cp ubuntu-21.04-server-cloudimg-amd64.img wen3.img
chown qemu:qemu wen3.img

virt-sysprep --root-password password:1 --uninstall cloud-init --selinux-relabel -a wen3.img --network --hostname=wen3

virt-install \
    --import  \
    --name wen3 \
    --ram=16384 \
    --vcpus=16 \
    --accelerate \
    --network network:default,model=virtio \
    --mac 02:ca:fe:fa:ce:33 \
    --debug \
    --wait 0 \
  --console pty \
    --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/wen3.img,bus=virtio,size=100 \
    --os-variant centos7.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some details on how to log into a new Ubuntu instance for the first time, to complement @Athafoud's answer.

In the OpenStack GUI, you manage your public/private keys under Project > Compute > Access & Security. Create an SSH key (e.g. by using `ssh-keygen` under Linux or macOS) and add it to the OpenStack keys by clicking on "Import Key Pair". (Or you can "Create a Key Pair" from within the OpenStack GUI and then export the keys to your workstation.)

When you create the new instance (VM), you have to specify this key as the "keypair" you will use to log in for the first time.

Once your new instance is up and running, connect to it via SSH as follows:

`ssh -i <keyfile> ubuntu@<instance>`

where `<keyfile>` is the name of the SSH key you associated with the instance, and `<instance>` is the hostname or IP address of the instance. This command logs you into the `ubuntu` account on the instance without asking for a password.

The `ubuntu` user has `sudo` privileges, so you can become root by typing `sudo -i` after login, and manage the VM as you please :-).