# Openstack, login to my instance

Tags: openstack, devstack

I've installed devstack, downloaded a trusty ubuntu server image, launched a heat flavor instance, created a public ssh key, ssh to my instance, all fine.

Now it may be a silly question but when ssh(ing) to the instance, how to login to the instance using the console provided by openstack dashboard?

Comment: See my answer here: [Login credentials of Ubuntu Cloud server image](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29143050/2279200), it may help you.

Answer (score 1):

You following format in your terminal

```
 ssh -i anuruddha.pem ubuntu@192.168.30.212
```

anuruddha.pem is your generated key pair path. ubuntu is your instances' default user. 192.168.30.212 is the ip address of your instance

For more info see [here](http://anuruddhall.blogspot.com/2015/03/creating-instance-in-openstack.html).

Comment: yes I did all of that but how to login using the horizon console not in my local machine, all I  have in the console is login:     ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new user and/or associate a password to connect through the console.

***passwd myuser***

Then connect you those new credentials.