# Devstack, default username and pass not showing in the console; Ubuntu cloud image

Tags: openstack, devstack

I installed ubuntu cloud image, I'm trying to login for cirros img, in the console shown by openstack, the default username/pass are printed in the console. But with Ubuntu trysty server cloud img nothing is displayed.

How t login ?

Comment: See my answer here: [Login credentials of Ubuntu Cloud server image](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29143050/2279200), it may help you.

Comment: Thanks I am able to ssh to Ubuntu so now I have to create a user to be able to use it in the openstack console right? and for that there is no pass for sudo

Comment: `ubuntu` user does not need a password for sudo. If you want to create a new sudo user, you have to add the name of the new user to sudoers (visudo command). For the new user the password is required by default to elevate into sudo

Comment: Could you help with this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30125928/openstack-working-from-my-instance-connecting-to-nova-clouds-ubuntu-cannot-init)